# Hadoop Informatica Log processing

Tags: parsing, hadoop, logging, informatica

I am working on a project involving creating a queryable set of data from fairly large Informatica log files. To do so, the files are imported into a Hadoop cluster using Flume, which was already configured by a coworker before I began this project. My job is to create a table from the data contained within the logs so that queries can be performed easily. The issue I'm encountering has to do with log file formatting. The logs are in the format:

Timestamp : Severity : (Pid | Thread) : (ServiceType | ServiceName) : ClientNode : MessageCode : Message

The issue is that sometimes the message field contains additional colon-delimited comments, for example a message could be [ x : y : z ]. When using HCatalog to create the table I cannot account for this behavior and instead results in additional columns.

Any suggestions? Normally I would use Ruby to separate the fields or replace the delimiter to keep the integrity when importing using HCatalog. Is there some pre-processing I can do cluster side allowing me to do this? The files are too large to handle locally.

Comment: You can run a Ruby script (or any other executable) with Hadoop Streaming utility. You can also implement such pre-processing in Pig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use a pig script and Python UDF. The pig script loads in the file then calls the Python script line by line to break the fields properly. The result can then be written to a friendlier CSV and/or stored in a table.